why can't i see the members of a conversation (typed as UnknownFutureValue)
For an exploration purpose of the capabilities of ms graph regarding teams, I use the following code:
GraphServiceClient gsc = GetGraphClient(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret);

ChatCollectionResponse chats = await gsc.Users[userId].Chats.GetAsync();
int cpt = 0;

if (chats != null && chats.Value != null) {
    foreach (Chat chat in chats.Value) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{++cpt:00000}: {chat.Id}");
        
        Console.WriteLine(chat.ChatType);
        try {
            ConversationMemberCollectionResponse? m = await
                gsc.Chats[chat.Id].Members.GetAsync();
            if (m != null && m.Value != null) {
                foreach (ConversationMember im in m.Value) {
                    AadUserConversationMember eu = im as AadUserConversationMember;
                    Console.WriteLine($" - {im.DisplayName} - {eu?.Email}");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception? ex) {
            while (ex != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("  - " + ex.Message);
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }
        }                
    }
}

I found this code only returns the most recent conversations (less than 24h it seems).
For me the mystery is that for one conversation I get the following result:
00020: 19:meeting_*********************************************
UnknownFutureValue
  - InsufficientPrivileges

This is not the only meeting_ of the list.

Why UnknowFutureValue, and
why InsufficientPrivileges knowing that the privileges were enough for the previous 19 conversations?


The error is related to a specific chatType. If you add request header prefer:include-unknown-enum-members to request GET /users/{id}/chats you should receive concrete value for chatType instead of unknownFeatureValue, but I'm not sure whether the SDK will able handle it.
